# i want to edit my restaurant data but i got this"The view company.views.edit_res didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

ValueError at /company/edit_res/1/ i got this error on "    F:\restaurant\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 307, in check_response" this location please guide me for successful edit this is my first learig project

views.py

```
def edit_res(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pi = ResRegister.objects.get(pk=id)
        fm = CompRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=pi)
        if fm.is_valid():
            fm.save()
        else:
            pi = User.objects.get(pk=id)
            fm = CompRegisterForm(instance=pi)
        return render(request, 'comp/edit.html', {'form': fm})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
app_name = 'company'

urlpatterns = [

    path('res_list/', views.res_list, name='res_list'),
    path('food_list/', views.food_list, name='food_list'),
    path('remove_res/<int:id>/', views.remove_res, name='remove_res'),
    path('remove_food/<int:id>/', views.remove_food, name='remove_food'),
    path('edit_res/<int:id>/', views.edit_res, name='edit_res'),
    path('edit_food/<int:pd>/', views.edit_food, name='edit_food'),
    path('add_food/', views.add_food, name='add_food'),
    path('cart_page/', views.cart_page, name='cart_page'),
    path('generate_invoice/', views.generate_invoice, name='generate_invoice'),


] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

edit.html

```
<!doctype html>
{% extends 'Comp_base.html' %}
{% block body %}
{% load static %}
<br><br>
  <div class="container">

      <h1>Update Information</h1><br>
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Update</button><br>

</form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're getting that error because the return statement was nested inside the if-statement, which means only return something if the request is a POST method. That is why it returns None if that condition fails. You can change it like so:

```
def edit_res(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pi = ResRegister.objects.get(pk=id)
        fm = CompRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=pi)
        if fm.is_valid():
            fm.save()
    else:
        pi = User.objects.get(pk=id)
        fm = CompRegisterForm(instance=pi)
        
    return render(request, 'comp/edit.html', {'form': fm})
```

Comment: I just edited my answer to bring the else-statement out as well. Try it now and see if you get the same error